# NSURLConnection originalRequest throwing exception in iOS 4 what can I use instead?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, sigabrt

In iOS 5 `[NSURLConnection originalRequest]` works fine, however in iOS 4 it throws an exception:

> -[NSURLConnection originalRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x65609a0

It seems like the iOS 4.3 SDK doesn't have a `originalRequest` method.

What can I use instead to get a `NSURLConnection`'s original request in iOS 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was this: I created a `NSString *origiOS4` and if the running OS is iOS4 then I initialize the string and give it the urls value. In the `connection:didReceiveData:` method then, I read the value from `origiOS4`.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (version < 5) {
        origiOS4 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:response.URL.absoluteString];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm diving into pre-existing code and I noticed it breaking in 4.3. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the NSURLConnection.h header file - you'll see the following comment:

```
When created, an NSURLConnection performs a deep-copy of the
    NSURLRequest.  This copy is available through the
    -originalRequest method.  As the connection performs the load,
    this request may change as a result of protocol
    canonicalization or due to following redirects.
    -currentRequest can be used to retrieve this value.
```

Since this method was introduced in iOS5, you won't be able to use it in iOS4.3 or earlier.  So in this case you will need to duplicate the functionality of the new method.

If you're using a very simple NSURLRequest object, it may be as simple as doing a [request copy] before you initialise the NSURLConnection, otherwise you'll need to look into how to implement a deep copy.  NSURLRequest does implement NSCoding, so you can probably archive and unarchive to make a deep copy if that's what you need.